# Error displaying data using datareader VB.NET and SQL Server

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to show the user role once the login success, but, I cannot obtain the behavior that I want. I'm a beginner and here a put my piece of code what I'm using now.

```
 Sub LoginSistema()
    Try
        AbrirConexion()
        Comando = New SqlCommand("select * from tbl_usuarioslogin where username = '" & frmLoginWindow.TextBox1.Text & "' and password = '" & frmLoginWindow.TextBox2.Text & "'")
        Comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Comando.Connection = Conexion
        Lector = Comando.ExecuteReader()
        If Lector.HasRows Then
            Lector.Read()
            If Lector.GetValue(1).ToString = "Victor" Then
                MsgBox("Bienvenido :) " + Lector(8).ToString())
                CerrarConexion()
                Lector.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Error al iniciar sesion en el Sistema.")
                CerrarConexion()
                Lector.Close()
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("No hay datos leidos de la base de datos.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

See ya,

Comment: Please provide detailed information of any errors that occur, including where they occur, or else describe EXACTLY how the actual behaviour differs from what you expect.  All you've done is basically said "here's my code, it doesn't work". We need you to be SPECIFIC.

Comment: Also, the way you're querying the database is very bad. The wrong data could generate exceptions that would prevent a legitimate user logging in and a malicious user could potentially delete or modify any data in your database.  Then there's the fact that you're storing passwords as plain text.  You should learn how to parameterise SQL queries and also to hash passwords.

Comment: Sorry for not be a little bit more specific. I want to once I put the username and password using textboxes in the login window form, in the button called Login can check if the data in the textboxes exists into database, and if exists that can show me a message with Welcome + user (based in the position of my column in the database of user roles) and pass to the action once the login be success. If not, I caught an exception and showing a custom message if the loggin fail.

Comment: About learning of using parameters and hashes, thanks, Im recently begin using vb.net and sql server programming, but, I will move in on learning your recommendations.

Comment: Holy Sql Injection hole, Batman! And plain-text password doesn't help, either.

Comment: And I ask for a second time, how does the behaviour of the code you have differ from the behaviour you want? You're currently testing the value of the second column and if it matches "Victor" then you're displaying the value of the ninth column.  Is that what you want to do?  If so, what's the actual problem?  If not, why are you doing it?

Comment: By the way, if you're only going to get zero or one row back then there's no point testing `HasRows` and calling `Read`.  Just call `Read` and it will either return `True`, in which case there's a row and you can access it, or return `False`, in which case there's no rows.  You would only use both if there might be zero, one or more rows and you want to do something specific in the case of there being zero.